# Combinatorial identities of the following sums

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n > 1$ be some natural number. I am looking for a closed-form expression for the following sums (they seem very natural, so I guess this is well-known):

$1+2^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+...+n$

$2^n+2 \cdot 3^{n-1} +...+ n(n+1)$

Comment: For the first sum, [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+8%2C+22%2C+65%2C+209%2C+732%2C+2780&language=english&go=Search) has a list of numbers and a recursive formula. The first eight terms of the second term are $2, 10, 38, 138, 516, 2040, 8588, 38476$, but do not have any entry in OEIS. However, you can contribute this sequence to OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/Submit.html).

Comment: "Too broad":  How about restating the problem as a request for analytic formal generating functions?  Not that I have an answer right now but that would be more definite.